# VS Code takes too long to be installed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I attempted to install Visual Studio Code on my Windows 11 laptop, which has an AMD 7 processor. Previously, I was able to use it without issues. However, after accidentally uninstalling it, I can no longer use it. Attempts to reinstall it, either by downloading it from the official website or using `choco install vscode` in the console, have been unsuccessful. When I try to install it it remains like this for hours.

[image]

Comment: Not enough info... reinstallation in Windoze can fail for many different reasons. If all else fails, reinstall Windoze, then install Visual Studio...

Comment: Bizarre unusual behavior like that in windows often happens when the OS has updates to install. If you have already rebooted your computer and/or tried manually updating in Settings, then it's probably time to reinstall Windows from a fresh ISO.

Comment: @spamsink this issue has 6 months. There were a lot of updated and reinstallations during that period.

Comment: @WileyRush I already reboot my laptop but I am still not able to install VS Code